# python get string from text file and serach from another text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have two text file  a.txt  b.txt  .
all text file has a lines for string

i want get all string from a.txt and serach in b.txt
if found just print true

a.txt

```
a
b
c
```

b.txt

```
g
h
a
m
```

thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
with open ("a.txt", "r") as first:
with open ('b.txt',"r" ) as second:
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the following? You might need to tweak it a bit (e.g., removing newlines/whitespaces at the end using, for example, `.strip()`) but it might be what you are after.

```py
with open ("a.txt", "r") as fh1:
    first = fh1.readlines()
with open ('b.txt',"r" ) as fh2:
    second = fh2.readlines()

for line in first:
    if line in second:
        print('True')
```